# Handling errors in looper/event loop interface

Tags: design, c++

I have a C++ class that spawns a thread that contains an event loop of sorts and the class provides an API to query the list of events that have occurred since the last call, i.e something like `std::vector<std::string> getEvents();`.

In case some sort of fatal error occurs in the event loop, I shut it down and log an error. I'm trying to figure out how this `getEvents()` API should communicate that the event loop is no longer running and that it won't return valid output.

Unfortunately, I'm working in an environment where exceptions are disabled so I'm not sure of the best way to handle this. I thought of adding a separate API so the client can query whether or not the event loop is still running but that seemed racy and not ideal.

What's a good approach for designing this?

Update: I think `std::optional` in C++17 is the best option.

Comment: What sort of benefit does shutting off exceptions provide?  Is this someone's idea of security by obscurity?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of couple of ways of dealing with errors/exceptional conditions when you are not allowed to throw exceptions. They are same in principle but differ in how you use the functions.

1. Make the return value of any function that could fail to be an `int` or a suitable `enum`. This will require you change the function signatures such that what you would return from the function will need to be an output argument.

   ```
   int getEvents(std::vector<std::string>& events);
   ```
2. Add an output argument to every function that could fail. The type of the argument could be a reference to an `int` or a suitable `enum`.

   ```
   std::vector<std::string> getEvents(int& errorCode);
   ```

Both the methods require that you test whether the function succeeded any time you make the call. You proceed to use the real output of the function only if the call succeeded.

When adopting the first approach, use:

```
std::vector<std::string> events
int status = getEvents(events);
if ( failed(status) )  // Assuming such a function exists.
{
   // Deal with the error.
}
else
{
   // Use events
}
```

When adopting the second approach, use:

```
int status = 0;
std::vector<std::string> events = getEvents(status);
if ( failed(status) )  // Assuming such a function exists.
{
   // Deal with the error.
}
else
{
   // Use events
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm working in an environment where exceptions are disabled ...

Oh dear.

That's a shame because I'd say that's exactly what you *should* be using here.

- Client calls getEvents()
- getEvents finds that the event loop isn't running and throws an Exception
- *Client* deal with ("handles") the fact that the other process is broken.

OK; so you're being told *not* to use Exceptions.
What are you being told to use *instead*?

I'm guessing that your fellow Developers have got some method of detecting these "unexpected but thought about" occurrences that the *rest* of would use Exceptions for...

Answer (score 0):

Simple:  define an `enum` for error codes and extend `getEvents` by an additional "output" argument like  `getEvents(ErrorCode &errorCode)`. If you need to return more information than just a number, make `ErrorCode` a class with all attributes required.

That is a standard way of returning errors in programming languages like C where  exceptions are not part of the language.